# How to change output format after randomizing an Array?

Tags: arrays, swing

I'm trying to randomize numbers 1 - 3 whenever a button is clicked and the result to be displayed in a JList (`myList`).

But when I click the button, the following text appears in the JList (no errors come up though):

`[Ljava.lang.Integer;@79de1d`

I then tried displaying the result in a JTextField and the results appeared as `[3,1,2]`, `[2,3,1]`, `[1,3,2]` etc.

How can I change the format of the Array output so that each number can be listed normally in the JList?

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
public void randomList()
    {
        Integer num[] = {1,2,3};      
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(num));
        model.addElement(num);
        myList.setModel(model);
        txtNum.setText(Arrays.toString(num));
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to add each element of the array to the list model, not the array itself.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Use a loop, and call addElement() for each element of the array. Also, you didn't post all your code, but I'm assuming you're usign a rax DefaultListModel. Don't use raw types. Use a DefaultListModel<Integer>.

Comment: Okay, what would be the correct syntax to specify each element of the array?

Comment: you got your answer from Lew. But this is quite basic stuff. You need to practice with simple exercises and lean to read the javadoc before even thinking about using Swing which is quite a complex beast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a new DefaultListModel and add the numbers one by one:

```
DefaultListModel<Integer> source = new DefaultListModel<Integer>();
for(int i : num)
  source.addElement(i);
list.setModel(source);
```

Comment: You sir, are a legend!

Comment: Thanks! Glad I could help.